# Targeting 1st, 6th, 11th post within a loop

Tags: wordpress, count

Trying to write a code to target the 1st, 6th and 11th post within a loop. This is what i have for the moment, and i was wondering if there is a better way to target those 3 posts.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
  <?php if ($count == 1) : ?>
      //do this
<?php elseif ($count == 6) : ?>
      //do this
<?php elseif ($count == 11) : ?>
      //do this
<?php else : ?>
      //do that
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Care to explain how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your code, you are incrementing $count at the beginning of the loop and setting $count = 1 before the loop. So you're actually targeting the 2nd, 7th, and 12th posts.

To answer your question, if you're doing the same thing to all three of the 1, 6, and 11 posts you could combine the if statements using the modulus.

```
if ( $count % 5 == 1 ) {
   //do something
}
```

The % (modulus) is calculating the remainder. So if $count = 9, then 9 / 5 = 1 with a remainder of 4...so 9 % 5 = 4.

In your case, you're targeting 3 items with a remainder of 1 (1 % 5, 6 % 5, and 11 % 5 all equal 1).

If you're doing different things to each of the 1st, 6th, and 11th posts then the approach you have now is fine. Just change the $count = 1 to $count = 0 before the loop.